# Finding a path using CSS Selector in Selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I am trying to find an element using CSS Selector, using Selenium (Java).

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="PayMeth" widgetid="PayMeth_0" id="PayMeth_0">
<div class="Icon GIFT" data-dojo-attach-point="pmN"></div>
<div class="paytMethLab" data-dojo-attach-point="pmN">Program Card<br> 
0000 000 0000 ****</div>
<div class="payMethAmtP" data-dojo-attach-point="pmAmtN">-$0.1</div>
</div>
```

I have used the following path but it is failing.

```
By.cssSelector("div[class=paytMethLab.contains(Program Card)]")
```

I want to get the text "Program Card".
Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a try with this xpath `//div[@class='paytMethLab' and text()[contains(.,'Program Card')]]`

Comment: @AppuMistri we are not allowed to use xpath :(

Comment: You are trying to locate the element and return the text contained or you are trying to find the element based on contained text? Given the HTML you posted, it looks like a CSS selector `div.paytMethLab` should get you the element that you want and then you get can get the text from it to return "Program Card". If you are trying to locate the element by contained text, the only way to do that is using XPath.

Comment: @JeffC I am trying to locate the text, not the element containing text, here which is "Program Card"

Comment: @Adrija It works for me, are you waiting for the element to be available ?

Comment: @AppuMistri it worked for me too, sorry my bad! But i need to use CSS Selector :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used and it worked :)

```
WebElement PayMeth = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.paytMethLab")));
String programcard = PayMeth.getText();
if(programcard.contains("Program Card"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: you don't have to specificy `div[class='']`, you can simply specify `div.className` as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple css that you can use.

```
div.paytMethLab
```

Here is the code

```
WebElement PayMeth = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.paytMethLab")));
 String programcard= PayMeth .getText();
    if(programcard.contains("Program Card"))
    {
        //your logic goes here.
    }
```

Comment: FYI - In general if you have spaces between the classNames then make sure to replace the `whitespace` with `.`.